# Amcharts - Maps: bad coordinates (lat/long) on a custom map (county level Romania)

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to add cities on a county map. The lat and long are drawn corectcly on the full size map(Romania level) but on the county map these are drawn wrong. I think I should rescale the map or lat/long of the city, I don't know...
How should I generate the county map in accordance with cities lat/long?

The code is listed below:
http://jsfiddle.net/xzAx7/33/

```
    var map;

AmCharts.ready(function() {
    map = new AmCharts.AmMap();
    map.pathToImages = "http://www.ammap.com/lib/images/";
    //map.panEventsEnabled = true; // this line enables pinch-zooming and dragging on touch devices
    map.balloon.color = "#000000";

    var wordlDataProvider = {
        mapVar: AmCharts.maps.Cluj,
        getAreasFromMap: true,
        areas: [
            { id: "FR", color: "#4444ff" },
            { id: "RU", color: "#4444ff" },
            { id: "US", color: "#4444ff" }
        ],
        images: [{
                    title: "ClujNapoca",
                    latitude: 46.85307355,
                    longitude: 23.63327696,
                    type: "circle",
            color: "red",
            scale: 0.5
                }, {
                    title: "Turda",
                    latitude: 46.5745618,
                    longitude: 23.78573862,
                    type: "circle",
            color: "red",
            scale: 0.5
                }]
    };

    map.dataProvider = wordlDataProvider;

    map.areasSettings = {
        autoZoom: true,
        selectedColor: "#CC0000"
    };

    map.write("mapdiv");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. You need to define "defs" properties (leftLongiitude, ...) when you create a custom map. This is specified in this article - https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/creating-custom-maps-for-javascript-ammap/
In the amCharts article is explained how you can get these "defs" properties.

I've changes the code below to understand how it works

```
"defs": {
    "amcharts:ammap": {
        "projection":"mercator",
        "leftLongitude":"22.607117",
        "topLatitude":"47.363798",
        "rightLongitude":"24.261932",
        "bottomLatitude":"46.384241"
    }
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xzAx7/35/